# Minimal coupling in general relativity

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, covariance

Consider the Einstein-Maxwell action (setting units $G_{N}=1$),

$$S = \frac{1}{16\pi}\int d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}\ (R-F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu})$$

where

$$F_{\mu\nu} = \nabla_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\nabla_{\nu}A_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}.$$

This describes gravity coupled to electromagnetism. The equations of motion derived from this action are

$$R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R = 8\pi T_{\mu\nu}$$
$$\nabla_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu} = 0.$$

---

1. Why does the electromagnetic field tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$ reduce to $\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}$ even in curved spacetime?
2. Would this not mean that the equation $\nabla_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu} = 0$ would also reduce to $\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu} = 0$ even in curved spacetime?

Comment: Because the connection is symmetric. If you right out $\nabla_\mu A_\nu$ in terms of the Christoffel's symbols and use that they are symmetric on the low indecies you get your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has already been answered in a comment but I'll elaborate a little bit.

$F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu $ if we assume that the connexion is torsionless such that $\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu} = \Gamma^\rho_{\nu\mu}$ which is always the case. (Apart from some strange setups in supergravity). We find:

$$F_{\mu\nu} = \nabla_\mu A_\nu - \nabla_\nu A_\mu = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\rho A_\rho - \partial_nu A_\mu + \Gamma_{\nu\mu}^\rho A_\rho = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$$

Note that the christoffel symbols only vanish in antisymmetric expressions. Furthermore:

$\nabla_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = g^{\mu\kappa}g^{\nu\omega}\nabla_\mu F_{\kappa\omega} = g^{\mu\kappa}g^{\nu\omega}(\partial_\mu F_{\kappa\omega} - \Gamma_{\mu\kappa}^\rho F_{\rho\omega} - \Gamma_{\mu\omega}^\rho F_{\kappa \rho})$

Such that here the christoffel symbols wil not vanish !

Comment: But can you not then write, in the last line, $-F_{\kappa\rho}=+F_{\rho\kappa}$ and cancel out the last two terms?

Comment: No because you get $g^{\mu\kappa}(\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\kappa} F_\rho^{\phantom{\rho}\nu} - g^{\nu\omega}\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\omega} F_{\kappa\rho})$. The two free indices $\nu$ are not on the same object so these two can never cancel !

Comment: You're right, I misread that :)